# Checking a property that involve vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

I´d like to know if it is valid this solution. I think not, but I can´t find the reason.

TASK:

Let $h : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable map. For $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ critic point of $h$ consider $$\phi : T_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \times T_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$$ $${([((\mathbb{R}^n,Id),v)],[((\mathbb{R}^n,Id),w)])} \mapsto X(Y(h))(p)$$ being $X,Y$ vector fields of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$X(p)=(p,[((\mathbb{R}^n,Id),v)]), \hspace{0.4cm} Y(p) = (p,[((\mathbb{R}^n,Id),w)]).$$ Prove that $\phi$ is bilinear.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

Let be $\xi_1 = [((\mathbb{R}^n),Id), v_1)]$, $\xi_2 = [((\mathbb{R}^n),Id), v_2)]$ and $\nu = [((\mathbb{R}^n),Id), w)]$. We get $$\phi(\xi_1 + \xi_2,\nu) = X(Y(h))(p) = \partial (Y(h) \circ Id^{-1})_p(v) = \partial (Y(h))_p(v) = \partial (Y(h))_p(v_1+v_2) = \partial (Y(h))_p(v_1) + \partial (Y(h))_p(v_2) = X_1(Y(h))+X_2(Y(h)) = \phi(\xi_1,\nu) + \phi(x_2,\nu).$$

It is valid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $X(Y(h))(p) = X(p)(Y(h)) \neq X(Y(h)(p))$, since $Y(h)$ is a differentiable map different to $Y(h)(p) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a real number.